# Is there any tutorial for Rails 3.2 that covers assigning an admin attribute to a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, boolean, admin, attr-accessible

Disclaimer: I'm using Rails 3.2. Specifically, in the Rails 3 in Action book:

The User model does have attr_accessible attr_accessible :email, :password, password_confirmation, :remember_me

The User model NOT have :admin listed, therefore it can't be mass-assigned to as part of params[:user].

---

The form_for block inside app/views/admin/users/_form.html.erb sets up a checkbox element to 
allow an admin to set a user as an admin:

`     <%= f.check_box :admin %>
      <%= f.label :admin, "Is an admin?" %>

---

The app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.admin = params[:user][:admin] == "1"  
if @user.save
```

The line @user.admin = params[:user][:admin] == "1" should set the admin attribute to true, but generates mass-assignment errors which prevent me from changing the @user.admin attribute to true.

---

I can set the admin attribute to true without mass-assigning via the console, along with defining a method in the User model:

```
def make_admin
  self.admin = true
end
```

This accomplishes the same thing, nothing fancy.

How do I get the admin attribute assigned to TRUE for the user to work using a view & controller via the checkbox?

Is there a way to remove or separate the admin parameter from params[:user][:admin])?

Answer (score 2):

Commenting out the `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict` line in the development.rb file moved me forward.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea to comment the mass assignement protection.

Why don't you add `:admin` to the list of `attr_accessible` if you want it to be mass assigned ?

And for information, when you type this :

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.admin = params[:user][:admin] == "1"  
if @user.save
```

It's not the `@user.admin = ...` which throw a mass assignment error, but the line `User.new(params[:user])`

Anyway, if you want to retrieve the value of the checkbox, but don't want to mass-assign it, try this :

```
admin = params[:user].delete(:admin)
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.admin = admin == "1"  
if @user.save
```

Don't forget to re-enable the mass assignment protection ;)